# remove items in list that's not exist in response from backend

Tags: flutter, dart

My logic is not the best at time.
I am fetching data from backend and adding them to a list.

And with some interval I am getting data again and I want to check if the item exists or not.
If it exists don't do anything. But if it don't exist add the item to the list that did not exist the first time.

1. So first I am getting data from backend.
2. Add the to a list.
3. Getting response from backend again, and if nothing changed from backend no items should be added.
4. If the backend is changed it should add item, if item is removed in backend the item should be removed but only the one that that was changed.

So my plan was the following:

```
var response = await getData("<endpoint>");
if (response == null) return;
    var data = dataFromJson(response); //Its a List with Strings

    for (var item in data!) {
      if (itemList.any((e) => e.id == item!.id)) {
        print("ID: ${item!.id} already exist");
      } else {
        itemList.add(item!);
      }
    }
```

The above code works for adding new items to the list. But how do I make the same thing for when I remove an item in backend and want to update the list depending if an item is added or removed.

I have tested using.

```js
itemList.removeWhere((e)=>e.id != item.id);
```

Do I need to have a second list and do some clever comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that you just have to overwrite your `itemList` with the data sent back from the backend :

```dart
if (response == null) return;
var data = dataFromJson(response); //Its a List with Strings
itemList = data;
```

This will update `itemList` with the data from the response so you don't have to compare the difference between them.
And if you want to avoid this assignment because you want to update `itemList` only when the backend data is different from what you have in your `itemList`, then you add this condition.

```dart
var data = dataFromJson(response);
if (!const IterableEquality().equals(itemList,data)){
  itemList  = data; 
}
```

don't forget to  :

```dart
import 'package:collection/equality.dart';
```

Comment: But will this keep the already added items in the list.

Comment: if they are still exists in the backend response i.e the data base then Yes

Comment: I think I should rewrite my question because I am getting data from backend depending on where I am on Google maps. So when moving I get data from map boundingbox

Comment: yes post a new question more detailed if you want